# converting an array into an array of objects with same key pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, angular-ui-router

i have an array like this: -

```
["119306.jpg","149426.jpg","157715.jpg","161706.jpg","171278.jpg","172313.jpg","179934.jpg","182047.jpg","182084.jpg","182261.jpg","183351.jpg","185276.jpg","189666.jpg","190304.jpg","191798.jpg"
```

I need to convert this into an array of objects like this:-

```
var images = [
{
    {
        id:"119306.jpg"

    },
    {
        id:"149426.jpg"

    },
    {
        id:"157715.jpg"

    },
    {
        id:"161706.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:"171278.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:"172313.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:"179934.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:"182047.jpg"
    }
}
```

];

The reason i am trying to do this is so i can inject $stateParams and my ui-sref will have an id placeholder. Whichever image i click, after it checks the code below:-

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
  if($stateParams.id == response.data[i].id) {
    $scope.oneimage = response.data[i].id;
  }
}
```

Basically, all i want to do is convert that array into an array of objects but with the same key pair for each one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map function. With array being your original objects, and the resulting array being arrayOfObjs;

```
var arrayOfObjs = array.map(function(jpg){
  return {id:jpg};
});
```

Your resulting array would look like this:

```
[
{id:"some.jpg"},
{id:"some.jpg"},
{id:"some.jpg"}
...
]
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I tried using map and for each but i instead decalred a new empty object and instead of retuning anything i did something like newObj.id = element <--- which obviously wouldnt work since it would add a new id property into the object with the last element of the array.